# sub string extracts in Hive

Tags: regex, hive

We have a string like:

ABC.XXXXXXX.USD.XX

and the task is to extract currency (USD in this case).
Options I tried returns nonsense:

```
select distinct 
    r.name
    ,regexp_extract(r.name,'\.(.{3})\.',1)
    ,split(r.name,'\.')
    ,split(r.name,'\.')[2]
from sales r
```

output:

```
 ABC.XXXXXXX.USD.XX    BC.   ["","","","","","","","","","","","",""]  <empty>
```

How come?

Comment: Might be due to the escaping? Try ``\\.``: `'\\.(.{3})\\.'`, `split(r.name,'\\.')`

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function in Hive is based on regular expressions. See the [language manual on the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hive/LanguageManual/UDF#String_Functions):

```
split(string str, string pat)
   Split str around pat (pat is a regular expression)
```

You specified the delimiter as `"\."`, that is an undefined escape sequence parsed as a mere `.` that, in regex, matches *any character*, thus, it split between each character, and also at the start and end of the string.

You need to escape the dot with the literal backslash that can be defined in a string literal as `"\\."`

Answer (score 0):

Just put that in square brackets like:

```
split(r.name,'[\.]')[2]
```